# Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout when run in genymotion device

Tags: android

When i run my app in genymotion virtual device occur error and my app crashed.Error is:

```
5-31 13:15:18.838 1205-1205/com.mypackage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage/com.mypackage.StarterActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

My app gradle dependency:

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
```

Note: My app work fine on real device.

Comment: could please share you app gradle deendency

Comment: @ismailalaoui i added gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure constraint layout is updated to latest version:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

And replace your xml tag names

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>
```

with

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```